# Equivalent of http://www.cplusplus.com/ for C# .net

Tags: c#, .net, reference, webresource

I've read through a lot of the "Learn C# .Net" questions just to see if this question was answered already (directly or indirectly).

I program mostly in C++ so I find the website http://www.cplusplus.com/ invaluable and there's rarely a day when it is not open in my browser!  However, I'm just wondering is there an C# .Net equivalent that people find themselves constantly referencing?

The best I'm aware of is:

http://stackoverflow.com

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336809.aspx

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/CatalogCSharp.htm

http://csharp.net

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget

http://csharp.net

Answer (score 0):

Since C#<sup>®</sup> is a registered trademark of the Microsoft® Corporation, wouldn't owning a domain name with "C sharp" in it be a violation of trademark?

I mean, I recall some jokers from 2600 Magazine about ten years ago who registered "fordsucks.com" and were subsequently sued. And Microsoft® isn't exactly known for being passive about litigious issues nowadays.

Comment: That's completely irrelevant. The OP is not looking for a website literally called "csharp.com", he is looking for a C# equivalent to cplusplus.com.

Comment: Actually, [Company Name]Sucks.com type sites were declared to be protected under free speech and not infringing upon trademarks.

Comment: C# is an open standard anyway: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm

Comment: +1 For the interesting diversion!!!  I know its subjective but I just meant a site of similar high quality\standard for c#